# Why does deleting a valid heap-allocated pointer give "free(): invalid pointer" error?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, destructor, delete-operator, reference-counting

I am new to C++ and am trying to do a very basic implementation of a shared_ptr (WIP). I am trying to delete a heap-allocated pointer in the destructor right after finding the underlying value by dereferencing. While the dereferencing happens fine, deletion of '''ref_count''' variable is causing problems. Can someone please help?
'''

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class shared_ptr{
 private:
  T* native_ptr_ = nullptr;
  int* ref_count_ = nullptr;

  inline void increment_count() {
    *ref_count_++;
  }

  inline void decrement_count() {
    *ref_count_--;
  }

 public:
  shared_ptr() {
    std::cout << "shared_ptr: empty constructor" << std::endl;
    native_ptr_ = nullptr;
    ref_count_ = nullptr;
  }

  shared_ptr(T* ptr) {
    std::cout << "shared_ptr: constructor" << std::endl;
    if (ptr) {
      native_ptr_ = ptr;
      ref_count_ = new int(1);
    }
  }

  ~shared_ptr() {
    std::cout << "shared_ptr: destructor" << std::endl;
    if (ref_count_) {
      decrement_count();
      if (ref_count_ && use_count() == 0) {
        std::cout << *ref_count_ << " " << *native_ptr_ << std::endl;
        delete ref_count_;
        delete native_ptr_;
        ref_count_ = nullptr;
        native_ptr_ = nullptr;
      }
    }
  }

  int use_count() const {
    if(ref_count_) {
        return *ref_count_;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  // case1
  int* temp = new int(0);
  shared_ptr<int> a1(temp);
  return 0;
}
```

'''

'''

```
shared_ptr: constructor
shared_ptr: destructor
0 0
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

'''

Comment: Is this everything you have? This code shouldn't be giving you that error.

Comment: A tip when you are debugging pointer problems: examine the actual pointer value, not the data that it's pointing at.

Comment: @OP Unless you place your version of `shared_ptr` within its own namespace, you should name it something else other than `shared_ptr`.  There already is a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I disagree, `std::shared_ptr` is already in a namespace. `using namespace std` is bad and should not be used.

Comment: Whether `using namespace std:` is bad isn't the point really.  A C++ programmer seeing simply `shared_ptr` in code will immediately believe what is being referred to is `std::shared_ptr`.  Anyway it is good style to create a namespace for names that could clash with `std::` names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator precedence is causing you problems.  You're actually decrementing the pointer, then deferencing the new address.  If you crank up your warnings, you'll get something like this:

```
p.cpp:35:7:   required from ‘shared_ptr<T>::~shared_ptr() [with T = int]’
p.cpp:58:26:   required from here
p.cpp:14:5: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
   14 |     *ref_count_--;
      |     ^
```

You can add parenthesis to de-reference the pointer before decrementing.

Comment: A correction to your last statement is required: `ref_count` _does_ need to be a pointer, but the OP's program just hasn't implemented copy-construction or copy-assignment from another shared pointer yet.

Comment: @paddy - Am I missing something?  Unless I'm reading the code wrong, `ref_count` and `native_ptr` will either both be `nullptr` or neither will be.  Could just check `native_ptr` and save an allocation, right?

Comment: It's clear the intent is to create a shared pointer idiom.  They have even stated that their program is a WIP.  It's actually a good thing they are implementing it piecewise and testing it in stages, unlike most people new to programming.  It's misleading to recommend changing `ref_count` to something that is not suitable for shared pointer usage, even though it's not required for the code as currently written.

Comment: @paddy - Fair enough.  Edited.

Comment: @paddy I just did. Thank you all!